# HC-05 to low cost AB shutter 3

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05

I'm trying to connect a HC-05 to AB Shutter3 module. However, when I try to search AB Shutter3 address via AT commands (`AT+INQ`) I could not find AB Shutter3.

I want to integrate both, so that I can send commands from an AB Shutter button click to HC-05.

I also want to know whether the HC-05 needs to be in master or in slave mode.

Comment: I agree with Majenko. According to [here](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/06/19/using-the-hc-06-bluetooth-module/) you can not do it with hc-05. You need a hc-06 for this at least.

Comment: Why is the HC-06 sufficient while the HC-05 not? AFAIK the HC-06 is a reduced version of the 05 (only slave instead of master/slave)

Answer (score 0):

I rather suspect the AB Shutter 3 is a Bluetooth HID device (like a keyboard or a mouse). The HC-05 can only communicate with Bluetooth Serial devices, such as the HC-06 or systems that can emulate a serial device (such as a computer or a smartphone).

You won't get them to communicate no matter how hard you hit them.